# Exclude deleted post edits from Suggested edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Over the past few days, I've encountered several suggestions for editing deleted posts.

Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30236729) of them. As you can see, [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807103/how-to-add-pixels-to-bounding-box-coordinate) was deleted 2 hours ago, and I came across it in **Suggested edits** right now.